# replace url (or every word who begins by) by only a word like "{URL}"

Tags: string, bash, perl, url, replace

Inside a bash variable (named $text), i want to replace every URLs by the word "URL"

```
$text="blah blah blah https://www.stackoverflow.com blah"
=>
$text="blah blah blah URL blah"
```

How to do that ?

A perl/sed/awk command which detects http:// and another for https:// ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: That's invalid syntax for variable assignment in bash. It is valid perl, though.

Comment: i add perl as you want...

Comment: Are you sure every 'URL' is going to be HTTP{s}? protocol? That you only care about those?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're super careful, [extended globbing](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) and [parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) can probably handle it in `bash`.

```
$: text="blah blah blah https://www.stackoverflow.com blah blah
> HTTP://google.COM/foo?bar
> more blah blah text."
$: shopt -s extglob nocasematch
$: newtext="${text//HTTP*(s):+([^[:space:]])/URL}"
$: echo "$newtext"
blah blah blah URL blah blah
URL
more blah blah text.
$: echo "$text"
blah blah blah https://www.stackoverflow.com blah blah
HTTP://google.COM/foo?bar
more blah blah text.
```

Comment: THANKS YOU !!! it perfectly fits my needs :)